# не работает уменьшение количество объектов в owlCarousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

есть слайдер [image: сам слайдер]

код слайдера

```
<div class="owl-carousel slider-one">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/spray.svg">
                                <p>Поддерживающая
                                    <br>уборка</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/mop.svg">
                                <p>Комплексная уборка</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/window.svg">
                                <p>Мытье окон</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/bucket.svg">
                                <p>Генеральная
                                    <br>уборка</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/cleaning-tools.svg">
                                <p>Уборка
                                    <br>после ремонта</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/tools.svg">
                                <p>Домашний
                                    <br>мастер</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/maid.svg">
                                <p>Домработница</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/oxford.svg">
                                <p>Химчистка</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/sofa.svg">
                                <p>Химчистка
                                    <br>мебели</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/cleaning.svg">
                                <p>Обработка
                                    <br>поверхностей</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

это код в php, а код в js вот

```
$(function() {
    $(".open-menu").on("click", function() {
        $("#popup-menu").fadeIn(400)
    }), $("#popup-menu .head-popup-menu .close-menu").on("click", function() {
        $("#popup-menu").fadeOut(400)
    }), $("li.submenu").on("click", function() {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle(500)
    }), $("#open-detail-list-works").on("click", function() {
        $(".detailed-list").toggleClass("active-list")
    }), $(".p-a").on("click", function() {
        $("#modal-login").fadeIn(500)
    }), $(".close-modal_p-a").on("click", function() {
        $("#modal-login").fadeOut(500)
    }), $(".open-mobile-amenities").on("click", function() {
        $(".open-mobile-amenities").css("display", "none"), $(".amenities .mobile-amenities .none").slideDown(500)
    }), $(".open-mobile-stock").on("click", function() {
        $(".open-mobile-stock").css("display", "none"), $(".stock .mobile-stock .none-stock").slideDown(500)
    }), $("#popup-menu").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "dark-3"
    }), $(".price-table-dry").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "minimal-dark"
    }), $("#popup-menu").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "dark-3"
    }), $(".open-list").on("click", function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(400)
    }), $(".slider-one").owlCarousel({
        dots: !1,
        loop: !0,
        margin: 10,
        nav: !1,
        autoWidth: !0,
        center: !1,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            1e3: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    }), $(".workers-slider").owlCarousel({
        dots: !1,
        autoplay: !0,
        autoplayTimeout: 3e3,
        loop: !0,
        margin: 10,
        nav: !1,
        center: !0,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1e3: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    }), $(".comments-slider").owlCarousel({
        dots: !1,
        loop: !0,
        margin: 10,
        nav: !1,
        autoplay: !0,
        autoplayTimeout: 5e3,
        autoplayHoverPause: !0,
        center: !1,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            1e3: {
                items: 2
            }
        }
    }), $(".stock-list-first").owlCarousel({
        dots: !0,
        loop: !0,
        margin: 10,
        nav: !1,
        autoWidth: !0,
        center: !1,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            1e3: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    }), $(".bxslider").bxSlider({
        minSlides: 1,
        mode: 'vertical',
        speed: 800,
        maxSlides: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        prevText: '<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>',
        adaptiveHeight: !0
    }), $(".bs-wrapper").addClass("container");
    var e = $(".slider-one");
    e.owlCarousel(), $(".slider-wrap .next").click(function() {
        e.trigger("next.owl.carousel")
    }), $(".slider-wrap .prev").click(function() {
        e.trigger("prev.owl.carousel")
    });
    var o = $(".stock-list-first");
    o.owlCarousel(), $(".slider-stock-wrap-first .next").click(function() {
        o.trigger("next.owl.carousel")
    }), $(".slider-stock-wrap-first .prev").click(function() {
        o.trigger("prev.owl.carousel")
    }), $(".phone-mask").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99"), $(".questions-answer .q-a .questions").on("click", function() {
        $(this).next().stop(!0, !0).slideToggle(700)
    })
}), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bx-wrapper").addClass("container")
});
```

при ширине в 600 должно быть 2 объекта, но их не два, а три[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
. Почему код не работает? Специально кинул весь js,ибо писал не я и может что-то переделывает

Comment: __1e3__ что это такое?? что за восклицательные знаки внутри конфигурации слайдера?? все уберите

Comment: в каком месте восклицательные знаки?

Comment: @peter у мня огромные пробелы между ними, хотя прописанно margin: 10,+как убрать мини стрелочки в нижнем левом углу(у меня помимо моих стрелок внизу ещё появилось ооооочень маленькая пара)

Answer (score 0):

Все работает только у вас не правильно написан код для слайдера

ВО первых

```
 dots: !1,
        loop: !0,
        margin: 10,
        nav: !1,
        autoWidth: !0,
        center: !1,
```

**Уберите все восклицательные знаки перед цифрами.**

Во вторых что это такое **1e3** ??

Напишите ширину экрана нормально .

И все сработает как внизу

```js
$(function() {
    $(".slider-one").owlCarousel({
        dots: 1,
        loop:0,
        margin: 10,
        nav: 1,

        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            900: {
              items:4
        },
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="owl-carousel slider-one">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Поддерживающая
      <br>уборка</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Комплексная уборка</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Мытье окон</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Генеральная
      <br>уборка</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Уборка
      <br>после ремонта</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Домашний
      <br>мастер</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Домработница</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Химчистка</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Химчистка
      <br>мебели</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://my-hit.org/storage/2014314_210x300x50x2.jpg">
    <p>Обработка
      <br>поверхностей</p>
  </a>
</div>
```